How to use bare metal Kubernetes with existing AWS Load Balancer (NLB)
I created a cluster manually with kubespray (NO cloud providers used) on AWS EC2 machines that I created myself. I have an AWS NLB that I created myself.
What is the proper way to configure Kubernetes Cluster with existing AWS NLB? So that the outside traffic get into k8s through AWS NLB (that is created manually by me).
